# Why do we have [python2.7] and [python3.x] as tags instead of [python2.x] and [python3.x]?

Tags: discussion, tags

Why do we have [python2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python2.7) and [python3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python3.x) as tags, instead of [python2.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python2.x) and [python3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python3.x)?

Also, I guess if anyone has Python1 questions, they'd just say [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python), since [Python1 is presumably forwards compatible with all versions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8141025).

---

Should we make Python2.x?

Comment: We have those tags because someone thought them to be useful to find questions they could answer.

Comment: a relevant search on meta: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=version+specific+tag

Comment: @rene - Any reason to make Python2.x?

Comment: No, there is no reason. IIRC Python 2.7 is the only relevant version.

Comment: older tags can be useful for people stuck with 2.5 or 2.6. Poor souls.

Comment: @rene: besides, we already have [tag:python-2.x]...

Comment: I rolled back the most recent edit because the details removed were important for understanding why the user was confused and posted this question in the first place.

Answer (score 8):

Python 2.7 will soon run out of maintenance - see http://www.pythonclock.org ... and we already have plenty more python tags (including the [python-2.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-2.x)):

[image: python tags]

(Some might be synonyms already)

I don't see the need to create new tags for languages that are older then 2.7 and not yet presented by their "individual" tag.

The general python tag [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) should always be put together with whatever specific tag you need, because often users only look for the main tag. See the multiple short descriptions in the image - they tell you as much.

Comment: Oh, I didn't try the auto-tag thingy beyond "Python", so I didn't notice...

Comment: None of these are synonyms (nor do they need to be).

Comment: Huh.. i am not the only person who knows that link...

Comment: @U9-Forward I picked it up on SO, might have been yours to begin with ;)

Comment: @PatrickArtner Lol :-) i got it from here: https://stackoverflow.com/users/8472377/austin

Comment: I wonder where Austin got it from ... now we just need somebody crawling through all of SO's comments - looking for the first one mentioning it and then build a spread-graph of early adopters parroting it :D

Answer (score 5):

We don't have a [python3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python3.x). We have a [python-3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.x), and we also have a [python-2.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-2.x). Note the dashes.

If [python3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python3.x) or [python2.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python2.x) somehow becomes an actual tag, it should be synonymized to the version with the dashes. It's not currently possible to suggest them as a synonym since they don't exist yet:

[image: Failed to propose synonym: The suggested tag must exist in the system before suggesting it as a synonym!]